# What is pinout of JFET in schematic. Is pin 1 really gate?

Tags: schematics, jfet, schematic

In the following schematic the J310 part, Q5 and Q6, are shown rotated.
If so shouldn't the pinouts show the gate as pin 3 instead of pin 1?
I thought he pinout of a J310 was 1-drain 2-source 3-gate.
I would not think that rotating the part would change the pinout.

I'm confused how to figure out which is the source, drain.

[image: Schematic containing JFET]

[image: J310 pinout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused how to figure out which is the source, drain.

JFETs can be assumed as symmetrical devices. So the drain and source are interchangeable.

Of course there are non-symmetrical JFETs i.e. having different GS and GD capacitances. But for most applications in practice this will bring negligible difference -- unless you are using the devices in high frequency applications.

Comment: Yes but is pin 1 really the gate.  The schematic shows pin 1 as the gate.  I'm really trying to understand how to interpret this schematic and I would not think that rotating a part in the schematic would NOT change the pinouts listed on the schematic.  I would think pin 3 is the gate.

Comment: @ditkin If it's J310 then the datasheet is correct. Sometimes the schematics shouldn't be relied on as the authors might have copied the symbol from somewhere else (e.g. another JFET with different pinout) so changed just the name and forgot about the pinout. Rely on the schematic about the general circuit operation and rely on the datasheet for the pin connections.

Comment: ditkin, you *should* be able to measure a diode-like junction between gate/source and between gate/drain with a multimeter. As Rohat says, the distinction between source and drain is more ambiguous - I'd doubt very much that a multimeter could tell the difference.